# Sql Query to create an analysis data according to age bracket

Tags: sql, oracle

Reframing my question -

Query#1

```
SELECT   
    person_number, 
    taxable_earn, 
    Basic_Life_EE,
    Tax_Units,
    Basic_Spouse,
    case 
        when Basic_Spouse is not null then age_depnt
        else NULL 
    end depent_dob,
    age_EE
FROM   
    (
        SELECT     
            pra.result_value , 
            pra.elementname, 
            prd.person_number ,
            pap.date_of_birth age_depnt,
            pra.date_of_birth age_EE
        FROM     
            pay_pay_relationships_dn prd 
        INNER JOIN pay_payroll_rel_actions pra ON 
            prd.payroll_relationship_id = pra.payroll_relationship_id 
        INNER JOIN pay_payroll_actions ppa ON 
            pra.payroll_action_id = ppa.payroll_action_id 
        INNER JOIN pay_all_payrolls_f pap ON 
            ppa.element_type_id = pap.element_type_id 
        WHERE 
            ppa.payroll_id = pap.payroll_id AND
            ppa.effective_date BETWEEN :p_start_date AND :p_end_date
    )
PIVOT    
    (
        SUM(result_value)
        FOR elementname IN ('taxable_earn' taxable_earn, 'Basic_Life_EE' Basic_Life_EE, 'Tax_Units' Tax_Units,'Basic_Spouse', Basic_Spouse)
    )
```

The above query is giving me data in the below format-

```
person_number        taxable_earn       Basic_Life_EE            Tax_Units      Basic_Spouse     depent_dob   age_EE
   10                 78.9                                          10.5                                        39
   20                 76.7                  10.2                                12.3                32          21
   30                  2.3                  10.3                    8.9         19.0                34          25
   40                                       14.3                    8.9         19.0                52          67
   50                                       3.2                                                                 20
   60                                       5.2                                                                 42
   70                                       7.2                                                                 49
   80                                       6.2                                                                 55
```

Now I want to create a query that segregates the data according to age bracket for the element Basic_Life_EE-

```
Age_Bracket        Count         SUM OF  Basic_Life_EE                   
    <=25            3                   23.7                                    
    26-29           
    30-34                                                                          
    35-39                                                               
    40-44           1                   5.2 
    45-49           1                   7.2        
    50-54          
    55-59           1                   6.2
    60-64
    65-69           1                   14.3                
    70+
```

The left side Age_bracket is fixed. Data count and sum of basic_life_EE will be null if there is no employee in the age range.
How can i use the query#1 to create the above analaysis?

Comment: How do you want to create age-bracket or is it already stored in any column ?

Comment: That's the thing .. it is not stored anywhere but is fixed so can be hard coded...

Answer (score 1):

You can do this, if you are fine to hardcode the age bracket

[SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3cd44e/12)

```
    select sum(basic_life_ee), count(1), '<=25' as age_bracket from Age_bracket_test where age_ee <=25
union
select sum(basic_life_ee), count(1), '26-29' as age_bracket from Age_bracket_test where age_ee between 26 and 29;
```

Another option is to do this way but this will only show the group which has data

```
with age_temp(min_age, max_age, age_bracket) as 
(select 0, 25, '<=25' age_bracket from Age_bracket_test
union
select 26, 29, '26-29' age_bracket from Age_bracket_test
union
select 30, 34,  '30-34' age_bracket from Age_bracket_test
union
select 35, 39, '35-39' age_bracket from Age_bracket_test
union
select 40, 44, '40-44' age_bracket from Age_bracket_test
union
select 45, 49, '45-49' age_bracket from Age_bracket_test
union
select 50, 54, '50-54' age_bracket from Age_bracket_test
union
select 55, 59, '55-59' age_bracket from Age_bracket_test
union
select 60, 64, '60-64' age_bracket from Age_bracket_test
union
select 65, 69, '65-69' age_bracket from Age_bracket_test
union
select 70, null, '70+' age_bracket from Age_bracket_test)
select sum(basic_life_ee), count(1),  age_bracket from Age_bracket_test, age_temp where age_bracket in ('<=25', '26-29', '40-44', '30-34', '35-40', '46-49', '50-54', '55-59', '60-64', '65-79', '70+') and age_ee between min_age and max_age group by age_bracket
```

Comment: If you see the table given above, it has data for age_EE for all the columns- taxable_earn       ,Tax_Units  . The above query is calculating "count" of elements other than the basic_life_ee element also...and not just the employees'age that has elements basic_life_ee

Comment: Sorry not able to understand your point. Could you please explain with an example if query is not giving correct result.